# How do I iterate this list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

All I have is one list like below:

```
list =  [ [{u'name': u'Peter'} , {u'name': u'Kevin'} , {u'name': u'Earl'}] ]
```

I need to get Peter Kevin Earl separately and use that as a parameter to query. How do I write my `for` loop?

I think there is one list in my list and inside the list has three dictionaries. I need to fetch per dictionary's value.

Comment: [key.values()[0] for key in temp[0]]

Comment: In the last dictionary, did you mean 'name'?

Comment: yes, I have found my answer in below comment

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
first_list = [[{u'name': u'Peter'},{u'name': u'Kevin'},{u'name': u'Earl'}]]

names = []

# You loop over the whole list
for element in first_list:

    # For each element, you loop over the elements inside it
    for object in element:

        # Now, object is each one of the dictionaries 
        names.append(object["name"])
```

The code above should works, and here you have a more pythonic answer

```
# By list comprehension
names = [ x["name"] for x in temp_list for temp_list in first_list ]

# If you don't know the how the key is named
names = [ x.values()[0] for x in temp_list for temp_list in first_list ]
```

It doesn't matter how many lists you have inside the first list because you are looping over it. And if there is only a list, the loop will iterate once.

Comment: you are welcome! could you mark the question as resolve?

Comment: how to resolve the question? sorry i am not familiar with this system

Comment: You could upvote my answer if it was useful or you could mark it as the answer to your question if it solves your problem. You can do this actions  at the left side of my answer.

Comment: I don't understand how this answer solves the problem, when the answer isn't even working on correct input.

Comment: according to this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: He writes 'number' despite of 'name' in the last dictionary. I have already edited the question but it must be accepted.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer, looks like it will work after 15 mins

Comment: Thanks you @ChesterLai.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque, did you understand the answer already?  Every comment or suggestion is welcome

Comment: @LuisGonzález, two things, 1. the term is not *compression*, it's *comprehension*  2. Don't use keywords as variable name, even for temporary use. (you've used *list*)

Comment: You are invited to edit my answer if you could improve it!

Comment: Actually, to me, @Tautvydas 's answer is more generic and pythonic, but I already changed your answer slightly keeping the logic same.

Comment: Yes,  I agree with you, but the only thing against the @Tautvydas 's answer is that he only loop over the first element in the list. In this case, it works because there is only a list inside 'first_list'. My solution could not be completely generic, but his answer neither. He soultion works, I have upvote it. What is better? I think is a matter of taste.

Comment: @LuisGonzález .. Your list comprehension is wrong, did you try it?

Answer (score 7):

This would do the trick:

```
inner_values = [dictionary.values()[0] for dictionary in list[0]]
```

This solution will get you value out of the inner maps no matter what the key is.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [[{u'name': u'Peter'}, {u'name': u'Kevin'}, {u'name': u'Earl'}]] # Note that this is a list containing another list, containing dictionaries.
names = [x["name"] for x in lst[0]]
```

I had to change your original list, because "Earl" was listed as a number. :)

Comment: Not all keys are 'name'. This won't get the last entry ('Earl').